# How to check if an integer is in a nested array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, nested

I have looked through a lot of various articles and have yet to find a solution that works. I have tried: Array, Arrays, ArrayUtil, and import java.lang.Object.org.apache.commons.lang.ArraysUtils; however nothing has worked.
Array, Arrays, and ArrayUtil before "contains()" results in error "cannot find symbol variable (Array/Arrays/ArrayUtil)", import java.lang.Object.org.apache.commons.lang.ArraysUtils results in error "cannot find symbol: class org"

http://pastebin.com/Dmwnf8FT

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html

Comment: Have you tried to implement the method yourself?

Comment: Here's an updated version with my failed method attempt: [link](http://pastebin.com/Dmwnf8FT). It gives the error "missing return statement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
```

rather than the `java.lang.Object` part.

You will also need to make sure reference to the jar is on your classpath. If you are using maven you can add the following dependency into your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit:**

Here's a code example that will return true/false if the integer is in the nested array or not. Compiled under jdk1.6.0_29 and works fine:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] myArray = {{1, 4, 5, 6, 9}, {9, 1, 3, 2}};

        System.out.println(arrayContain(myArray, 2));
    }

    public static boolean arrayContain(int[][] myArray, int valueToFind) {
        if (ArrayUtils.contains(myArray, 1)) return true;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (ArrayUtils.contains(myArray[i], valueToFind)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns the error "package org.apache.commons.lang does not exist"

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. I imported the package; however it still gives either the error: "cannot find symbol: variable ArrayUtils" or "cannot find symbol: method contains"

Comment: It might be the syntax since in the Commons Lang doc it gives this: "contains(xxx[], xxx)" as the contains function; however when I use that it throws even more errors at my face.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Seems there was another problem farther up in the code. Thanks.